# Process.env not accessible while writing playwright-ct component testing?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, playwright, playwright-test

I am using playwright for component testing, I have a following dir. structure in my next.js project.

```
./playwright
 - component
     ./ MyComponent.spec.tsx
     ./ MyComponent.tsx
     ./ index.html
 - fixtures
 - index.ts
```

Unfortunately process.env is not accessible in MyComponent.tsx?

I can access them in `MyComponent.spec.tsx`.

How I am loading them at the moment is e.g -

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config({ path: './env/.env.test', override: true });
```

in. `playwright-ct-config.ts`

My concern is to load them in MyComponent.tsx.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, I recommend filing an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem, seems like it very important concept when it comes to playwright-component testing.

The test runs in the Node.js process while the component is created inside a real browser in a separate process. process is not a part of Web API, this is why you can't access it from your component. You can use page.evaluate() to run javascript code in the browser context:

```
test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
  await page.evaluate(() => (window as any).TEST_ENV_VAR = 'test_value');
});

test('should work', async ({ mount }) => {
  const component = await mount(<App />);
  await expect(component).toContainText('Test');
});
```

and then in your component:

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
  const { shareEvent } = useAnalytics();

  console.log('TEST_ENV_VAR = ' + (window as any).TEST_ENV_VAR);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => shareEvent("PDP")}>shareEvent</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

I have extended this research further nevertheless you can also pass .env variables as an OBJ and then assign it to window.env inside page.evaluate().

Something like this:

```
test.beforeAll(async ({ page, mount }) => {
  const next_app_analytics_enviroment = {
    analytics_url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ENVIRONMENT,
  };

  await page.evaluate((next_app_analytics_enviroment) => {
    (window as any).ANALYTICS_URL = analytics_url;
  }, next_app_analytics_enviroment);

});
```